# C Iterating through char array

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, char, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void) 
{
  int n, i, j, k;
  char a[10][10];
  for (i = 0; i<10; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j<10; j++)
    {
      scanf(" %c", &a[i][j]);
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i<10; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j<10; j++)
    {
      if (strcmp(&a[i][j], "I") == 0)
      {
        a[i][j] = 'H';
      }
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i<10; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j<10; j++)
    {
      printf("%c", a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }


  return 0;
```

This code is supposed to change all "I" in all rows to "H" as it iterates through all chars in the array while comparing if the current char is "I". 
The example input and expected output of it would be:

```
--IHH---I-
-H--------
----------
----H-----
----IH----
----H-----
----H-----
-H--------
---------I
-HI--H---I


--HHH---H-
-H--------
----------
----H-----
----HH----
----H-----
----H-----
-H--------
---------H
-HH--H---H
```

But the real output is;

```
--IHH---I-
-H--------
----------
----H-----
----IH----
----H-----
----H-----
-H--------
---------I
-HI--H---H
```

As we can see only the 9x9th "I" changes to "H". I do believe that the problem is within the for loop as it **only** does the job at the last one. Which means the if statement works, but the iteration is flawed.

There are no error messages.

Comment: Don't use `strcmp` on something that's not a string. Compare characters directly: `a[i][j] == 'H`'. `strcmp` *requires* a NUL terminated string. You do not have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (strcmp(&a[i][j], "I") == 0)
```

should be replaced by

```
if (a[i][j]=='I')
```

As `&a[i][j]` is not a proper string (do not generally contain a `'\0'` at the end), so you never get a match unless you are lucky. In this case you are lucky at 9,9.

Comment: And since arrays are sequential in memory -- the only character you could "get lucky" with would be the last in the last row `:)`

Answer (score 1):

For starters declare variables in the minimum scope where they are used.

For example this declaration

```
int n, i, j, k;
```

only confuses readers of the code. For example it is unclear seeing this declaration where the declared variable `n` is used in the code if it is used.

Secondly do not use magic numbers like 10. Instead use named constants.

For example the array could be declared like.

```
enum { N = 10 };
char a[N][N];
```

And in loops you could write for example

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
    {
        scanf( " %c", &a[i][j] );
    }
}
```

It seems your array does not contain strings.

So the condition in the if statement

```
  if (strcmp(&a[i][j], "I") == 0)
  {
    a[i][j] = 'H';
  }
```

is invalid also because you are going to check only one character of the array with the character `'I'` not a sub-array of the array with the string literal `"I"`.

Rewrite the statement like

```
  if ( a[i][j] == 'I' )
  {
    a[i][j] = 'H';
  }
```

You could output the array simpler using only one for loop like

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    printf( ".*s\n", N, a[i] );
}
```